# Creating list of lists from dictionary with irregular levels of nesting

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

I have a dictionary from a cURL call in Python 3.8 and I would like to create a list  with information from just two keys to then write into a csv file.

The dictionary has actually just one key-value pair whose value is a list of dictionaries that contain the information I need. Within the nested dictionary, I'm interested in the key-value pairs 'conceptId' and 'fsn' (which is another nested dictionary with two key-value pairs, of which I only need 'term').

Here's a snippet of the dictionary with two 'items', although the real file is much larger.

```
res_json = {'items': [{'conceptId': '15964901000119107', 'active': True, 'definitionStatus': 'PRIMITIVE', 'moduleId': '900000000000207008', 'fsn': {'term': 'Atypical atrial flutter (disorder)', 'lang': 'en'}, 'pt': {'term': 'Atypical atrial flutter', 'lang': 'en'}, 'id': '15964901000119107'}, {'conceptId': '10811961000119109', 'active': True, 'definitionStatus': 'FULLY_DEFINED', 'moduleId': '900000000000207008', 'fsn': {'term': 'Cardiac arrest due to incomplete miscarriage (disorder)', 'lang': 'en'}, 'pt': {'term': 'Cardiac arrest due to incomplete miscarriage', 'lang': 'en'}, 'id': '10811961000119109'}]}
```

Desired Output:

```
output = ['15964901000119107', 'Atypical atrial flutter (disorder)'], ['10811961000119109', 'Cardiac arrest due to incomplete miscarriage (disorder)']
```

Here's my code so far ([flatten_json](https://towardsdatascience.com/flattening-json-objects-in-python-f5343c794b10))

```
#Flatten json 
def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}

    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(y)
    return out



flat = flatten_json(res_json)
json_normalize(flat)
output_list = []

for k, v in flat.items():
    if "conceptId" in k:
        output_list.append(v)
    if "fsn_term" in k:
        output_list.append(v)
        
for k, v in flat.items():
    if "fsn" in l:
        output[k] = v
```

This returns a single list with values in alternate order, but not a list of lists that I can write into csv.

```
>>>output_list: ['15964901000119107', 'Atypical atrial flutter (disorder)', '10811961000119109', 'Cardiac arrest due to incomplete miscarriage (disorder)']
```

How could I improve my code?

Comment: Given this site helps solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. It seems to me this question is more suited to be asked in the  [Code Review Forum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Code Review is a question and answer site for peer programmer code reviews. Please read the relevant guidance related to how to properly ask questions on this site before posting your question.

Comment: My problem is indeed specific and technical in nature. I'm asking for a way to go from point a to point b showing my attempt so far and where I'm stuck... Seems to be the standard way to ask questions around here in my experience. Thanks for the link though and sorry if I offended you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I needed to create a simpler dictionary with just the value of 'items' i.e. a list of dictionaries, and then simply call the key-value pairs I needed and add them to a list.

```
items = {}

    for k, v in res_json.items():
        if k == 'items':
            items[k] = v
        
output = sorted([[x['conceptId'], x['fsn']['term']] for x in items['items']])
```